# Geometry calculation using Pandas UDF

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, pandas

I am creating Pandas UDF to calculate the Geometry length .The following is the code which I created to calculate Geometry length.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd
from shapely import wkt

@pandas_udf('double')
def GeometryLength(geom):
    wkt_to_geom=pd.Series(wkt.loads(geom))
    wkt_to_geom = wkt_to_geom.to_crs(4326)
    return  wkt_to_geom.length
```

```
Inventory.withColumn("geom_length",GeometryLength(Inventory.geometry))
```

I am getting an error like

PythonException: 'TypeError: Only str is accepted.', from , line 8. Full traceback below:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3758.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3758.0 (TID 47345) (10.139.64.7 executor 28): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'TypeError: Only str is accepted.', from , line 8. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 8, in GeometryLength
File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/shapely/wkt.py", line 22, in loads
return geos.WKTReader(geos.lgeos).read(data)
File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/shapely/geos.py", line 327, in read
raise TypeError("Only str is accepted.")
TypeError: Only str is accepted.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to provide the complete error (with line number) and an indication of which line that is.

Comment: @Vince edited the question

Comment: Cant you use [.length()](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.length.html)? Do you have a pandas df with wkt strings? If so add a sample of it to your question, including line 8 which is causing the error